# Getting an object by name

Tags: python, class

Is it possible to create an instance of a class by giving its name, e.g.:

```
instance = "TestXYZ"()
```

Assuming that TestXYZ is imported by a class that imports the code above and TestXYZ is defined as:

```
class TestXYZ(object):
   ...
```

Comment: It is possible using `globals()["TestXYZ"]()`, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: Because I don't like to pass the exact class object, but I know the name.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to pass the class itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The mechanics depend on how you import the class:

```
>>> globals()["TestXYZ"]()
<__main__.TestXYZ object at 0x10f491090>
```

or

```
>>> getattr(sys.modules["test_module"], "TestXYZ")()
<test_module.TestXYZ object at 0x10cf22090>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a reference to an object from current namespace using:

```
klass = globals()['TestXYZ']
```

Then you can create an instance of the class:

```
instance = klass()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why do you want to do this, but instead of using `globals()` I'd suggest you to create a dictionary here:

```
class Foo:
   pass

d = {'Foo':Foo}
ins = d['Foo']()
```

Or move the class to some other module:

```
import some_module                
ins = getattr(some_module, 'Foo')()
```